# Can't install MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I really don't wanted to ask question about this, but I run out of ideas.

I have bought new VPS which has Ubuntu Server 14.04 x86_64.

First I tried to install it via this [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system).

I have added GPG key and added list file. Then I run `sudo apt-get update` and it just hangs for 15 minutes in `[Waiting for headers]` section.

I wanted to install older version (3.0.9). It also hangs at this section. Sometimes update finishes successfully and when I try to install it says that packages are not authenticated and **hangs even I click to yes**. Then after long wait it says that connection is failed.

I thought that my `apt-get` is broken and I tried to install another software(sqlite3) and it installed successfully. That means, that package manager works fine.

At last I wanted to install mongoDB from tarrball. I type in my folder this command:

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.1.tgz
```

And I get this:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:06 --:--:--     0
```

This means that it is not downloading. I know that curl works fine.

This is happening about for two days. Is MongoDB has some kind of issues regarding to their repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the below link and its working fine

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04